# WinForms and NHibernate, databindings and sorting

Tags: winforms, nhibernate, data-binding, componentone, c1flexgrid

My final goal is to have a Grid with multi column sorting (by Ctrl-Click on the column headers) using data from NHibernate. For that purpose I plan to use ComponentOne's FlexGrid for WinForms. According to it's documentation it supports sorting if the given DataSource does so.

I'm not yet sure if I'm going to use paging. But if so, sorting should definitely take place inside or below NHibernate.

- How is sorting supported by Winforms Databindings?
- Are there any samples/classes supporting a bindable/sortable way connecting a Grid with NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the interface `IBindingListView` which supports multicolumn sorting and set the implementor as datasource. It should work with Datagridview, don't know if FlexGrid supports it though.